# Php, MySql Join two tables and limit nested records

Tags: php, mysql

I've been killing my self for the past two days, trying to figure out a query.

I'm joining two tables, one users, and one comments. Comments are nested on parent_id. The problem is I cant order records based on date created, if using LIMIT clause.

The idea is to pull x number of records, and also included children within.

I have created SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/540f46/3

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @GurV I want to display x number of comments, and include all children comment as well. And sort by date descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output you mentioned below, I am assuming you want get latest three comments which don't have any parent (parent_id = 0 so 8,5,4)  and all their children (6,7).

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.user_id, c.parent_id, c.body, c.created, u.name
FROM
    `comments` AS c
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id
    FROM
        `comments`
    WHERE
        page = 'main' AND parent_id = 0
    ORDER BY created DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 3) AS temp ON temp.id IN (c.id , c.parent_id)
        LEFT JOIN
    users AS u ON u.id = c.user_id
ORDER BY c.created DESC;
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/540f46/10)

Comment: still not good. Based on your SQL Fiddle, It should display the last 3 comments with id's 8,5, and 4 as well as children with id's 5 and 6

Comment: Aren't the children 6 and 7?

Comment: By adding "AND parent_id = 0", now it completely ignores children, which is not what I want. I want to display children as well